# NSJSONSerialization, NSURLSession, Unicode in application/json responses

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization

I am using NSURLSession to communicate with web servers, and NSJSONSerialization to decode JSON. I am having trouble interpretting emoji characters.

For example, I have a JSON file at: https://www.virtualsanity.com/unicode.json

The content of the file is:

```
{"\uf4a9": "\uf4a9"}
```

The key and value in the dictionary is "\uf4a9". I believe that is a properly-escaped  character.

I have this Swift code running on iOS 9:

```
let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.virtualsanity.com/unicode.json")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
let dataTask = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
    print("encoding: ", urlResponse?.textEncodingName)
    if let responseData = data {
        if let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) {
            if let dictionary = json as? [String: String] {
                for (key, value) in dictionary {
                    print("key: \(key), value: \(value)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Unable to deserialize json")
        }

    } else {
        print("No response data")
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

I expect both the key and value of the resulting dictionary to be a  character. Instead they are garbage characters.

I am hoping someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the unicode for  is `\u1F4A9`, try this in a playground:

```
print("\u{1f4a9}")
print("\u{f4a9}")
```

Comment: I couldn't make \u1F4A9 work, but I could make \ud83d\udca9 work. Are web services encoding  as \uf4a9 just doing it wrong, or is there something I should do to make my decoding more tolerant? Thanks.

Comment: I've seen this before and every time it has been the web service what is wrong